# NetBeans Junit5 Tests-Output ignore DisplayName Nested-Format

Tags: netbeans, junit5

I do not get the names from the annoations "@DisplayName" as a test result in NetBeans. Only the names of the test functions are shown. The grouped display of the nested tests is also ignored.

[image]

Source code

```
@DisplayName("test facade")
public class TestFacadeTest {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("senseless test")
    public void test(){
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("tests - compareStringNullSave")
    class CompateStringNullSaveTestGroup {
    
        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() { 
        }
    
        @Test
        @DisplayName("both identical")
        public void Test1(){
            String str1 = "Test123";
            String str2 = "Test123";
            Assertions.assertTrue(TestFacade.compareStringNullSave(str1, str2));
            Assertions.assertTrue(TestFacade.compareStringNullSave(str2, str1));
        }
    
        @Test
        @DisplayName("Identical text but different uppercase and lowercase letters")
        public void Test2(){
            String str1 = "Test123";
            String str2 = "test123";
            Assertions.assertFalse(TestFacade.compareStringNullSave(str1, str2));
            Assertions.assertFalse(TestFacade.compareStringNullSave(str2, str1));
        }
    } 
}
```

Extract from the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    [...]
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <configurationParameters>
                        junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate = *
                        junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true
                        junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class
                    </configurationParameters>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What do I have to set so that the test display in NetBeans shows the DisplayNames and uses the nested grouping?

NetBeans version: 12.0
Java version: 11 (OpenJDK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven added support for the `@Display` annotation in the `3.0.0.0-M4` [version](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Surefire_Extensions_and_Reports_Configuration_for_.40DisplayName) of the surefire plugin. Also, you need to configure the parameters of `statelessTestsetReporter` and `statelessTestsetInfoReporter` extensions to allow for NetBeans to match display names correctly.

So currently (01.2021), you can use  `3.0.0.0-M4` or newer versions of the surefire plugin, and the version of JUnit should be more than 5.5.2. Something like that should work:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <statelessTestsetReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>true</usePhrasedFileName>
                    <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
                </statelessTestsetReporter>
                <statelessTestsetInfoReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5StatelessTestsetInfoReporter">
                    <usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>true</usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>
                </statelessTestsetInfoReporter>
                 <properties>
                    <configurationParameters>
                       junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate = *
                       junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true
                       junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class
                    </configurationParameters>
                </properties>
            </configuration>                                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Here how it looks in my case:

```
@DisplayName("Display Name of class")
public class testClassSimple {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Display name of method 1")
    public void testMethod1() {
    }
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Display name of method 2")
    public void testMethod2() {
    }
}
```

[image]

As for nested grouping and the `@Nested` annotation, currently, NetBeans doesn't support nested grouping of test results in the test result window. Probably it's better to use different classes for such tests instead of nested classes.